# SQL or django query to find the similar entries

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to return the user a list of similar tasks. Two tasks A and B are considered similar if all the words in task A exist in task B or vice versa.
I tried the query given below but couldn't get the required result.

```
SELECT t1.task
FROM todolistapp_todo t1
         LEFT JOIN todolistapp_todo t2
                    ON
                        t1.task in (t2.task) and  t1.id != t2.id;
```

I'm able to do this by the nested loop. But I want to do it with minimum complexity.

```
similar = set()
for task in tasks:
    for nested_task in tasks
        if (task.task in nested_task.task or nested_task.task in task.task) and task.id != nested_task.id:
            similar.add(task)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
[similar.add(similar_task) for similar_task in tasks if tasks.filter(task=similar_task.task).count()>1]
```

I'm on phone then sorry if not working :)